# Getting basic info of a user who is logged in into my website through google api

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-authentication, google-signin, userinfo

This is the web page which will be redirected to it after logged in:

```
// get_user_info.php
<?
    $gClient = new \Google_Client();
    $gClient->setApplicationName('Login to Pronexo');
    $gClient->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/pronexo/public/login/login_through_api/');
    $gClient->setClientId('849746924921-ueqhqvtbb6l7ccfrcq4j405bvej03bm7.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $gClient->setClientSecret('W7DdT0QmATW-3ZVJMO55jsfY');
    $gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
    $gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
    $oauth2 = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
    $userInfo = $oauth2->userinfo;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($userInfo);
    die;
```

The result is like this:

[image]

And here is the result of `Google_Client {#229 > }`

[image]

Also I've checked all items of the result but there is no user info. As you know, I have to get the email, name etc of the user who is logged in into my website through google php api. Anyway, any idea how can I access that info?

Comment: I cannot see what is in 'Google_Client {#229 >}', but I guess it is in there.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware There isn't https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSTKB.png

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, looking at the manual this is what you need to do: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people I'm sorry, I am not using this, so I cannot really help, I can only see that this differs from what you do.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for the link you provided, but it is in JavaScript syntax, I use PHP.

Comment: Oh dear, yes, of course.

Comment: I hope your `client_secret` in question (not in images) is redacted already ;)